# Странное поведение async/await в WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, async-await

Разбираюсь в async/await. Вот такой код в WinForms (чтобы был UI-контекст):

```
        private async void Parent(){
            Write("Parent() start.");
            var context = SynchronizationContext.Current;
            Task task = Task.Run(()=>ChildAsync(context));
            while (!task.IsCompleted)
            {
                Write("loop");
                await Task.Delay(1000);
            }
            Write("Parent() done.");
        }

        private async Task ChildAsync(SynchronizationContext context)
        { 
            await Task.Delay(3000);
        }

        public void Write(string message){
            richTextBox1.AppendText($"\n{message}");
        }
```

Почему в коде метода `ChildAsync` вызов функции `Write()` мешает дальнейшему выполнение кода, но при этом не мешает задаче завершиться (ведь сообщение `Parent() done.` появляется):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом если `Write()` вызвать после `await`, то это не мешает выполнению задачи:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И еще меня сильно смущает, что программа выводит сообщение "loop" хотя бы один раз - если `Write()` вызывает эксепшен и завершает задачу, то почему программа все же один раз входит в цикл?

Изменение задержки не помогает:

```
        private async void Parent(){
            Write("Parent() start.");
            var context = SynchronizationContext.Current;
            Task task = Task.Run(() => ChildAsync(context));
            while (!task.IsCompleted)
            {
                await Task.Delay(5000);
                Write("loop");
            }
            Write("Parent() done.");
        }

        private async Task ChildAsync(SynchronizationContext context)
        {
            Write(".......ChildAsync() done.");
            context.Post((x) => Write(".......ChildAsync() done"), null);
            await Task.Delay(3000);
        }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### Дополнение - отлов ошибок из другого потока:

Заключил код по созданию task'a в try-catch, но он не ловит ошибку. Почему?

```
       private async void Parent(){
            Write("Parent() start.");
            var context = SynchronizationContext.Current;
            Task task = null;
            try
            {
                task = Task.Run(() => ChildAsync(context));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(task.Exception.InnerException.Message);
            }

            while (!task.IsCompleted)
            {
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                Write("loop");
            }
            Write("Parent() done.");
        }
```

Comment: вы вызываете `ChildAsync` на тред пуле `Task.Run(()=>ChildAsync(context));` и удивляетесь тому, что оно падает при попытке доступа к UI контролу (`Write(".....");`)?

Comment: 1) Передача контекста в метод != запуску метода в контексте, потому вот это `ChildAsync(SynchronizationContext context)` - не имеет смысла. Что передавайте, что не передавайте, результат будет тот же

Comment: 2) доступ к UI элементу `richTextBox1.AppendText($"\n{message}");` должен быть выполнен из того же потока, где этот элемент был создан, а не просто любого потока с контекстом синхронизации. Хотя у вас, как я уже написал, вот это `ChildAsync(SynchronizationContext context)` не создает контекст синхронизции, оно в принципе ничего не делает.

Comment: О, значит она падает, спасибо. Но почему это падение не приводит к моментальному завершению ``task`` и выходу из ``While()``? Посмотрите, там все же пишется один раз "loop".

Comment: потому что постановка задачи в пул потоков может требовать времени большего, чем выполнения пары инструкций в текущем потоке, то есть код просто успевает дойти до `Write("loop");` до того, как таск упадет

Comment: Мне надо угадать как и куда вы их вставили? :)

Comment: @tym32167, прошу прощения - в комментарий не дает вставить ни картинку, ни нормальный кусок кода. 

Я просто поменял очередность ``Write("loop")`` и ``await Task.Delay(1000)`` плюс к тому изменил 1000 на 5000. Результат тот же - "loop" выводится один раз

Comment: не надо писать это в комментарии, пишите всё это в вопрос. Я по вашему тексту ничего не понял. Возьмите код, что вас смущает, вставьте в вопрос, напишите чем он вас смущает, чтобы любой мог просто скопировать ваш код, вставить куда то себе, запустить, увидеть ваше проблему и пояснить что происходит. Пока что я ни кода не вижу, ни проблему вашу не понимаю

Comment: @tym32167, добавил в вопрос.

Comment: ну так в чем проблема? У вас падает таск, вы из таска не видите сообщений. Код успевает зайти в цикл, в цикле вы ждете 5 секунд и пишете в бокс. Какие проблемы?

Comment: Я понял. Вы, наверное, думаете, что эксепшон в таске должен выкидывать вас из цикла. Нет, тот эксепшон остается в таске (если вы не делаете `await mytask`), то есть раз в основном потоке вы успели зайти в цикл, то код в цикле выполнится, хоть час ждите. Вот если вы `await Task.Delay(5000);` поставите перед циклом `while`, а не внутри цикла, то тогда да, в цикл не попадете, за 5 сек таск усапеет упасть

Comment: @tym32167, я понял свою ошибку (даже как-то неловко) спасибо! Может быть оформите ваш пост как ответ? Я тогда смогу его "лайкнуть".

Comment: никаких неловкостей, тут все учатся. Сделал ответом, если он вам помог, то поставьте галку. Если понравился - лайк. Если ни то ни другое - забейте :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы, наверное, думаете, что эксепшон в таске должен выкидывать вас из цикла. Нет, тот эксепшон остается в таске (если вы не делаете `await mytask`), то есть раз в основном потоке вы успели зайти в цикл, то код в цикле выполнится, хоть час ждите. Вот если вы `await Task.Delay(5000);` поставите перед циклом while, а не внутри цикла, то тогда да, в цикл не попадете, за 5 сек таск успеет упасть

Comment: Подскажите, почему "ошибка доступа к элементу из другого потока" не отлавливается на уровне создания task'a? Я дополнил вопрос кодом.

Comment: @AlexIlyin у вас есть поток А, в нем вы запускаете задачу, которая выполняется в потоке Б. Все исключения (ну, почти все), что возникнут в потоке Б - это проблемы потока Б, потоку А не проблемы потока Б чихать. Если вы хотите словить исключение таска в потоке А, вы можете написать `await Task.Run(() => ChildAsync(context));`, или, когда ваш `Task` закончится, [проверить его состояние](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/exception-handling-task-parallel-library).

Comment: Как мне правильно написать лямбду, чтобы ``Task.Run();`` возвращал значение, которое я смогу присвоить переменной ``task``?

Comment: @AlexIlyin какое значение и как это относится к вашему изначальному вопросу?

Comment: @AlexIlyin tym имеет ввиду, что для разных проблем вы должны задавать разные вопросы

Comment: @tym32167, понял вас, если не разберусь сам, то создам новый вопрос.